# I have a repetitive code, need hints on how to write it more efficiently without using for a loop

Tags: r

I am using the below code to get a subset by selecting the rows corresponding to specific quantiles for 3 columns from my data frame.

The below code works fine I just want to know if there is some way to not repeat myself; what if I had many more columns and wanted to add same lines over and over.

My teacher use to tell us that one should try to not use for loops.  I am only using 3 columns so its not so bad to repeat myself thrice but still give me hints on how to start thinking about writing this more efficiently, Thanks.

```
CustomSort = function(dt,colA1,colA2,colA3, colB1,colB2,colB3,colC1,colC2, colC3){
    select_data = dt[( dt[[colA1]] >= quantile(dt[[colA1]], seq(0,1,1/colA2))[[colA3]] 
                     & dt[[colA1]] <= quantile(dt[[colA1]],seq(0,1,1/colA2))[[colA3+1]] &
## That was selection qualifiers for 1st col next the second. 
                       dt[[colB1]] >= quantile(dt[[colB1]], seq(0,1,1/colB2))[[colB3]] 
                     & dt[[colB1]] <= quantile(dt[[colB1]],seq(0,1,1/colB2))[[colB3+1]] &
## The immediately above statement uses quantifiers for second column to limit data by.
                       dt[[colC1]] >= quantile(dt[[colC1]], seq(0,1,1/colC2))[[colC3]] 
                     & dt[[colC1]] <= quantile(dt[[colC1]],seq(0,1,1/colC2))[[colC3+1]]
## And that was 3rd column quantifier
                      ) , ]
## All that remains is return the dataset
                 return(select_data)
    }
```

I would appreciate some pointers to encourage me with coding.

Let me illustrate the code with the example of output:

```
> quantile(d8_bball$Salary, seq(0,1,.1))
  0%      10%      20%      30%      40%      50%      60%      70%
  300000   323500   355000   489200   950000  2000000  3000000  4000000
 80%      90%     100%
 7230000  9000000 26000000
> quantile(d8_bball$Home.Runs, seq(0,1,.1))
  0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100%
 0.0  3.0  5.0  8.0  9.8 12.0 15.0 18.0 22.6 29.0 51.0
```

Now I can get the data corresponding to the 90th quantile of 'Salary' column and between 50th and 60th quantile for 'Home.Run' columns with the below call to this function (note: I set the 'colA2' and 'colA3' parameter to 1 to include every thing from this 'Runs' column).

```
> CustomSort(d8_bball[,c('Runs','Home.Runs','Salary')],"Runs",1,1,"Home.Runs",10,6,"Salary",10,10)
Runs Home.Runs   Salary
 66        15  12666667
 39        14  17000000
 53        12  12357143
111        15  12500000
```

And If I choose 1's for all col*2 and col*3 parameters I would be returned all the rows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask] a question and how to post a [mcve].

Comment: Further to @Gaber-ber 's comment,  it would help enormously if you provided an example of your `data.frame`, plus a description of what your function is trying to do, and then an example output of what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first rule of programming ist, if you have some code that is repeating it self put it in a function :-)

The selection part from the different columns in your code is a perfect example. Lets put that in a function getQuantile

```
getQuantile = function(dt,columnName,inverseStepLength,segment) {
  dt[[columnName]] >= quantile(dt[[columnName]], seq(0,1,1/inverseStepLength))[[segment]] &
    dt[[columnName]] <= quantile(dt[[columnName]],seq(0,1,1/inverseStepLength))[[segment]]
}
```

substituting this into your code should look something like this

```
CustomSort2 = function(dt,colA1,colA2,colA3, colB1,colB2,colB3,colC1,colC2, colC3){
  select_data = dt[( getQuantile(dt,colA1,colA2,colA3) &
                       ## That was selection qualifiers for 1st col next the second. 
                       getQuantile(dt,colB1,colB2,colB3) &
                       ## The immediately above statement uses quantifiers for second column to limit data by.
                       getQuantile(dt,colC1,colC2, colC3)
                     ## And that was 3rd column quantifier
  ) , ]
  ## All that remains is return the dataset
  return(select_data)
}
```

That is already much easier to read and if you need to change something yo only need to change it in one place.

Now you asked what if I want to consider more columns? Well we can handle that if we put all the colXz parameters into a named List

```
colParameters = list(Runs = c(inverseStepLength = 1,segment = 1),
                     Home.Runs = c(inverseStepLength = 10,segment = 6),
                     Salary = c(inverseStepLength = 10,segment = 10))
```

using this structure and the functions lapply and Reduce
we can make your code even more flexible

```
CustomSort3 = function(dt,parameters){
  select_data = dt[lapply(names(parameters),function(colName){
    getQuantile(dt,colName,parameters[[colName]]$inverseStepLength,parameters[[colName]]$segment)
    }) %>% 
      Reduce("&",.), ]
  ## All that remains is return the dataset
  return(select_data)
}
```

There you have a purely functional implementation that scales freely all you have to do is to add a new entry to the parameterlist.

Now I have to admit that since you haven't submited any example data (and I am to lazy to create my own) that I am shooting a bit from the hip here and there might be some bugs in the code but the main principle should be correct.

Comment: The principles are excellent, thank you very much.  (I'll be mindful of providing an example data) but you got my question very well and provided me with coding exercise that I hope to remember what I learnt here.